# Scaling Write Intensive App (LAMP, MySQL) (Catalog Style Application)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, replication, scaling

I was wondering if there's anyone out here who has experience with write-intensive data due to file import.

The main requirement is for the business users to be able to import a data that represents relationships between master tables. They should be able to export the same in real-time ( as much as possible).

Setup:

- front-end (php) application writes on a MASTER database.
- Replication Setup
      - Master DB is replicated to two SLAVE DB servers.
- one of the SLAVE server is used as "read" database for front-end UI interactions (heavy queries).
- The same SLAVE server is also used for "EXPORTING" data based on a query that has been previewed on the front-end. (Lots of JOIN table).

The main challenge has been replication log. The users are not happy with the performance & data not being available on the front-end even though the files they've import has been processed already. Replication LAG is the culprit.

Moving to NoSQL i.e. is the LONG Term goal. Still want to improve the performance for now. By the way, the application is used internally but is hosted in a well-known hosting company. Number of users is around 150 users.

Imported data is around 200k - 800k lines. Each line represent a single row.

Any inputs would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you investigated why the lag occurs, and I wonder what the lag actually is?

Comment: Why is moving to "NoSQL" a long term goal?. (Full disclosure, I question the term "NoSQL" -- what is wrong with having a standardized query language that works with many databases? I can appreciate people wanting more flexible databases for web app development and other uses, but the problem IMHO is not the fact that a database supports SQL -- it is the performance, modeling, and integrity characteristics of a database that really matter)  Do you think you can model your data more efficiently in a non-relational database?

Comment: For performance and scalability we have considered NoSQL (i.e. MongoDB) as our LONG term path. Our data are simple enough to be modeled in non-relation database. The amount of data & the data availability requirements isn't simple.

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that play a part in improving MySQL replication lag.  Perhaps this podcast about MySQL replication on Youtube by their DBA might provide you with some tips & pointers:

http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail3299.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bug Magnet. I'll check this one out.

Answer (score 0):

@Wrikken,

(Answering via the answer box)

Yes, lots of "inserts" and updates. The application makes use of temporary tables (i.e. real physical table with some prefix) to insert preliminary data. And does a lot of INSERT INTO .. SELECT * FROM ..

This is causing a lot of statements being replicated to the SLAVE which in the end temporary tables are being dropped. I have already recommeded that such type of table should be excluded from  the list of tables to be replicated and instead of using INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM  the application should just SELECT everything from  build the INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements on the application memory space and execute the SQL statment. It should lessen the number of temp table related statements from being replicated.